# Retrieve AWS App Config Configuration from ReactJS APP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to use AWS AppConfig Service within my ReactJS App but I am 
having problem with CORS.

When I try to fetch my configuration with

```
AppConfig.getConfiguration({
  Application: 'XXXXXXX', /* required */
  ClientId: 'XXXXXXX', /* required */
  Configuration: 'XXXXXXX', /* required */
  Environment: 'XXXXXX', /* required */
  ClientConfigurationVersion: '1'
}, (err, data) => {
  console.log("err = ", err);
  console.log("data = ", data);
})
```

I am getting:
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

If it matters, I am using Amazon System Manager document as configuration source.

I am guessing there is a CORS policy configuration for AppConfig/System Manager service just like for the S3 and API Gateway services but I can't find it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: typically, you shouldnt hit AWS API through browsers bc it can expose your access key/secret. Rather you should hit AWS API Gateway, which then invokes the service or lambda proxy. You would enable CORS on API Gateway in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the recommended way? Is there any guide/ tutorial on how to properly use AppConfig from web app?

Comment: you wont find a guide for browsers because its not a recommended path. Though its not called out, the do say "You can use AppConfig with applications hosted on EC2 instances, AWS Lambda, containers, mobile applications, or IoT devices"; nothing about browsers. Anytime a credential/secret is put into a browser, it can be extracted by a user of your domain.